# Problem to populate a Tableview on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

### Code N°1:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayTmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

[arrayTmp addObject:@"line 1" ];
[arrayTmp addObject:@"line 2" ];

self.list = arrayTmp;
[self.tableView reloadData];
[super viewDidLoad];
[arrayTmp release];
```

### Code N°2:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayTmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

NSString *fieldName = [[NSString alloc] init];
fieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Ligne1"];
[arrayTmp addObject:(NSString *) fieldName];
[arrayTmp addObject:@"line 2" ];

self.list = arrayTmp;
[self.tableView reloadData];

[super viewDidLoad];
[arrayTmp release];
```

*Codes N°1 & N°2 do exactly the same job: they populate a tableview. My problem is with the code N°2:he displays the tableView but if I move the tableView with the finger, the iphone  freeze. The Debugger shows the following message: "GDB:Program receive signal: "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION".
I don't see what it is wrong. Has someone an idea of the problem ?
Thank you in advance.*

Comment: could you also provide a backtrace of when it crashes?

Comment: can you post the code for the "self.list" property?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that `self.list` does not retain the array, and when filling the table view you add references to the strings in that list. Your property should look like;

```
@property (retain) NSArray* list;
```

This is not a problem in the first example because the strings are literal - e.g. they are embedded in your program and are never deallocated.

The second example creates a temporary string, and although its reference is incremented when added to the array it will later deallocated and destroyed when the array is released.

Also this code;

```
NSString *fieldName = [[NSString alloc] init];
fieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Ligne1"];
```

Is going to result in a memory leak. You are allocating a new string, then changing the value in the pointer to be the result of the stringWithFormat call. If you wish fieldname to persist then the correct code would be;

```
NSString *fieldName = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Ligne1"] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your very good advices. As you suggest, I retain the array in my @property:

```
  @property (retain) NSArray *list;
```

### If in my code I put:

```
 NSString *fieldName = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"line 1"] retain];
[arrayTmp addObject:fieldName];
[arrayTmp addObject:@"line 2" ];
```

it's working!

### But if I put:

```
NSString *fieldName = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"line 1"] ] retain];
[arrayTmp addObject:fieldName];
[arrayTmp addObject:@"line 2" ];
```

it's display well the tableview but if I move the tableView 2 or 3 times with the finger, the iphone freeze.And unfortunately, I need to use stringWithFormat & stringWithUTF8String in order to populate my tableView from a database.

The error is still "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". But I don't know how to perform a backtrace. The Debugger shows:

## 0  0x300c8c18 in objc_msgSend

## 1  0x30b524dc in -[UILabel text]

## 2  0x30c07b44 in -[UITableViewCell layoutSubviews]

## 3  0x30a74020 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) _layoutSublayersOfLayer:]

## 4  0x31dd20f0 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers]

## 5  0x31dd2000 in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded

## 6  0x31dd1774 in CAContextCommitTransaction

## 7  0x31dd143c in CATransactionCommit

## 8  0x3026a0ec in __CFRunLoopDoObservers

## 9  0x30269920 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific

## 10 0x30269326 in CFRunLoopRunInMode

## 11 0x31563e60 in GSEventRunModal

## 12 0x30a4feb8 in -[UIApplication _run]

## 13 0x30a5961c in UIApplicationMain

## 14 0x000020bc in main at main.m:14

asm  obj_msgSend 0x300c8cc04:1
0x300c8c04  <+0000>  teq    r0, #0  ; 0x0

0x300c8c08  <+0004>  moveq  r1, #0  ; 0x0

0x300c8c0c  <+0008>  bxeq   lr

0x300c8c10  <+0012>  stmdb  sp!, {r3, r4, r5, r6}

0x300c8c14  <+0016>  ldr    r4, [r0]

### 0x300c8c18  <+0020>  ldr    r5, [r4, #8]

0x300c8c1c  <+0024>  ldr    r6, [r5]

0x300c8c20  <+0028>  add    r3, r5, #8  ; 0x8

0x300c8c24  <+0032>  and    r5, r6, r1, lsr #2

0x300c8c28  <+0036>  ldr    r4, [r3, r5, lsl #2]

0x300c8c2c  <+0040>  teq    r4, #0  ; 0x0

0x300c8c30  <+0044>  add    r5, r5, #1  ; 0x1

0x300c8c34  <+0048>  beq    0x300c8c54

0x300c8c38  <+0052>  ldr    ip, [r4]

0x300c8c3c  <+0056>  teq    r1, ip

0x300c8c40  <+0060>  and    r5, r5, r6

0x300c8c44  <+0064>  bne    0x300c8c28

0x300c8c48  <+0068>  ldr    ip, [r4, #8]

0x300c8c4c  <+0072>  ldmia  sp!, {r3, r4, r5, r6}

0x300c8c50  <+0076>  bx ip

0x300c8c54  <+0080>  ldmia  sp!, {r3, r4, r5, r6}

0x300c8c58  <+0084>  b  0x300c8c5c

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should use code 2

```
NSString *fieldName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Ligne1"];
NSMutableArray *arrayTmp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:fieldName, @"line2", nil]; //I would suggest using @"Ligne1" instead of fieldName if possible

self.list = [arrayTmp retain]; //This will make sure even after releasing arrayTmp, list is not affected
[self.tableView reloadData];

[arrayTmp release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies.

At the end, I resolve my problem by:

-adding a "retain" to my NNString fieldName

-removing a "release" on a variable in the tableView method "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Thank again for your helpfull support !

Answer (score 0):

```
self.list=[NSArray arrayWithArray:arrayTmp];
```

Just allocate self.list .
This is craeting bad exec. Because you are not allocating memory to list.

Retaining will not solve the problem